# Distributed alternatives to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, storage, distributed, distributed-system

I have a curious question.

What are some distributed and scalable ***alternatives to hadoop***. Am looking for some distributed file systems like **HDFS** which can be used as a cheap and effective storage and would like a data processing engine(batch/real-time) on top of it. I know Spark can be a good alternative. But I would like to use this system as a file archive which is distributed,fault tolerant and scalable.Is there any apt solutions ? Suggestions are welcomed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are some other alternatives to Hadoop and Apache Spark. Cluster Map Reduce, Hydra and Conclusion, they are all relatively good for big data projects. Read more here 
https://datafloq.com/read/Big-Data-Hadoop-Alternatives/1135

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Is there any alternatives other than those mentioned in that article. Basically,I need a file archive which is distributed,fault tolerant and scalable.

Comment: Take a look at Sphere and Riak

Comment: @FrakOdoom Cluster Map Reduce does not qualify since it is an algorithm rather than File System. Apache Spark operates in memory, but flushes to HDFS for persistence reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you still looking into alternatives, this Gigaom article may help:
https://gigaom.com/2012/07/11/because-hadoop-isnt-perfect-8-ways-to-replace-hdfs/
By default Spark flushed to HDFS.

Since HDFS is open source alternative to GFS(Google FS), You can use a connector to GFS(Google FS is available via Google Cloud Platform Storage services) ... there is a catch: it is expensive on massive data transfers between nodes/clusters. Hadoop was not designed for realtime data, but less dynamic data. I hope this helps somehow.

- MapR claims 20% faster than regular HDFS(but underlying FS is HDFS) https://mapr.com/why-mapr/
- NetApp has an alternative to HDFS as well http://www.netapp.com/us/solutions/applications/big-data-analytics/index.aspx

All above links are the Gigaom article I shared. 
I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thank you! But am not looking into this currently!

Comment: P.M statement about MapR-FS "...but underlying FS is HDFS" is not correct. MapR-FS is a distributed, highly available file system, that is not based on HDFS for its implementation. MapR-FS has its own implementation and way of organizing data on disk. BUT MapR-FS is accessible using the HDFS API, this means that not only you can work with MapR-FS like any distributed storage, but you can also run Hadoop applications on it.